# How can I limit flash movie to work only on single domain? not even in embedded browser activex

Tags: actionscript-3, activex, flash

How can I limit flash movie to work only on single domain. For eg what I need to do if I want flash swf to work only on example.com and it should not work if -
1. opened/embedded from other domain xyz.com
2. Downloaded
3. opened in embedded IE Activex Controls

Thanks.

Comment: just an FYI, it's extremely easy to decompile source code, so if what your trying to avoid is another developer "stealing" your work you should look into an ActionScript obfuscator like SecureSWF.

Comment: Thanks a lot PatrickS. I din't know that as I am new to this site. I'll accept the answers for all of my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write it in a function, so add it to any flash file easily:

```
function checkCP() {
  var pathStr:String = loaderInfo.url;
  var siteStr:String = "example.com";
  if (pathStr.indexOf(siteStr) != -1) {
      Play();
      //gotoAndPlay("main")
  } else {
      trace("this app only available for example.com")
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
  if( this.loaderInfo.loaderURL != "http://example.com/index.swf" )
        return
  else
     init();
```